# Unexpected string error when dynamically injecting js script

Tags: javascript, string, escaping, syntax-error, code-injection

I need to execute a insert and execute javaScript in the following way:

```
$("body").append("<script>//Some Code</script>");
```

I have tried following two encoding methods

1. Manually move everything to the same line and replace all double quotes with single quotes using search and replace

   ```
   Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/benPearce/vaxo00eb/
   ```
2. String escape the javaScript using [stringescape_tool](http://www.htmlescape.net/stringescape_tool.html)

Both of these methods result in "Unexpected string" syntax errors. If anyone can help me out I'd be greatly appreciative!

The Script I need to inject

```
  seal_gif_url="images/nortonseal.gif";


  dn="www.mysite.com";
  sap="getnortonsealimage.js";
  splash_url="https://trustsealinfo.verisign.com";
  tpt="transparent";

  language="en";
  u1=splash_url+"/splash?form_file=fdf/splash.fdf&dn="+dn+"&lang="+language;

  function vrsn_splash() {
    tbar = "location=yes,status=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=560,height=500";
    sw = window.open(u1,'VRSN_Splash',tbar);
    sw.focus();
  }

  {
    var ver=-1;
    var v_ua=navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    var re=new RegExp("msie ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
    if (re.exec(v_ua) != null)
     ver = parseFloat( RegExp.$1 );
    var v_old_ie=(v_ua.indexOf("msie")!=-1);
    if (v_old_ie) {
     v_old_ie = ver < 5;
    }

    function maction(e){
      if (document.addEventListener) {
        var seal=(e.target.name=="seal");
        if (seal) { vrsn_splash(); return false; }
      } else if(document.captureEvents) {
        var tgt=e.target.toString(); 
        var seal=(tgt.indexOf("splash")!=-1);
        if (seal){ vrsn_splash(); return false; }
      }
      return true;
    }

    function mouseDown() {
      if (event.button==1){
        if (v_old_ie) { return true; } else { vrsn_splash(); return false; }
      } else if (event.button==2) { vrsn_splash(); return false; }
    }

    document.write("<a HREF=\""+u1+"\" tabindex=\"-1\" onmousedown=\"return mouseDown();\" target=\"VRSN_Splash\"><IMG NAME=\"seal\" BORDER=\"true\" SRC=\""+seal_gif_url+"\" oncontextmenu=\"return false;\"></A>");

    if((v_ua.indexOf("msie")!=-1) && (ver>=7)) {
      var plat=-1;
      var re=new RegExp("windows nt ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
      if (re.exec(v_ua) != null)
        plat = parseFloat( RegExp.$1 );

      if (plat >= 5.1) {
       document.write("<div style='display:none'>");
       document.write("<img src='https://extended-validation-ssl.verisign.com/dot_clear.gif'/>");
       document.write("</div>");
      }
    }

    if (document.addEventListener){ 
      document.addEventListener('mouseup', maction, true); 
    } else {
      if (document.layers){
        document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN); document.onmousedown=maction;
      }
    }

    function resized(){
      if(pageWidth!=innerWidth || pageHeight!=innerHeight){
        self.history.go(0);
      }
    }

    if(document.layers){
      pageWidth=innerWidth; pageHeight=innerHeight; window.onresize=resized;
    }
  }
```

Comment: This doesn't really make sense. If you've got "some code", why isn't it just in your script?

Comment: use "<\/script>" instead of just "</script>", or call it from an external script file.

Comment: Using *document.write* after the load event has occurred isn't a good idea as it will clear all existing content before writing the new content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the theory is behind this but there was an unnecessary set of parenthesis enclosing a block of code that was causing the error. See altered javaScript below.

```
 seal_gif_url="images/nortonseal.gif";


  dn="www.mysite.com";
  sap="getnortonsealimage.js";
  splash_url="https://trustsealinfo.verisign.com";
  tpt="transparent";

  language="en";
  u1=splash_url+"/splash?form_file=fdf/splash.fdf&dn="+dn+"&lang="+language;

  function vrsn_splash() {
    tbar = "location=yes,status=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=560,height=500";
    sw = window.open(u1,'VRSN_Splash',tbar);
    sw.focus();
  }


    var ver=-1;
    var v_ua=navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    var re=new RegExp("msie ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
    if (re.exec(v_ua) != null)
     ver = parseFloat( RegExp.$1 );
    var v_old_ie=(v_ua.indexOf("msie")!=-1);
    if (v_old_ie) {
     v_old_ie = ver < 5;
    }

    function maction(e){
      if (document.addEventListener) {
        var seal=(e.target.name=="seal");
        if (seal) { vrsn_splash(); return false; }
      } else if(document.captureEvents) {
        var tgt=e.target.toString(); 
        var seal=(tgt.indexOf("splash")!=-1);
        if (seal){ vrsn_splash(); return false; }
      }
      return true;
    }

    function mouseDown() {
      if (event.button==1){
        if (v_old_ie) { return true; } else { vrsn_splash(); return false; }
      } else if (event.button==2) { vrsn_splash(); return false; }
    }

    document.write("<a HREF=\""+u1+"\" tabindex=\"-1\" onmousedown=\"return mouseDown();\" target=\"VRSN_Splash\"><IMG NAME=\"seal\" BORDER=\"true\" SRC=\""+seal_gif_url+"\" oncontextmenu=\"return false;\"></A>");

    if((v_ua.indexOf("msie")!=-1) && (ver>=7)) {
      var plat=-1;
      var re=new RegExp("windows nt ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
      if (re.exec(v_ua) != null)
        plat = parseFloat( RegExp.$1 );

      if (plat >= 5.1) {
       document.write("<div style='display:none'>");
       document.write("<img src='https://extended-validation-ssl.verisign.com/dot_clear.gif'/>");
       document.write("</div>");
      }
    }

    if (document.addEventListener){ 
      document.addEventListener('mouseup', maction, true); 
    } else {
      if (document.layers){
        document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN); document.onmousedown=maction;
      }
    }

    function resized(){
      if(pageWidth!=innerWidth || pageHeight!=innerHeight){
        self.history.go(0);
      }
    }

    if(document.layers){
      pageWidth=innerWidth; pageHeight=innerHeight; window.onresize=resized;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("body").append($("<script>", {
    text: "//Some code"
}));
```

The `</script>` in your string is being interpreted as the end of the Javascript that contains your jQuery code.

The problem is in the code in the script body. This line has quoting problems:

```
document.write('<img src='https://extended-validation-ssl.verisign.com/dot_clear.gif'/>');
```

it should be:

```
document.write('<img src=\\'https://extended-validation-ssl.verisign.com/dot_clear.gif\\'/>');
```

I think it's also necessary to double the backslashes in this line:

```
document.write('<a HREF=\''+u1+'\' tabindex=\'-1\' onmousedown=\'return mouseDown(); \' target=\'VRSN_Splash\'><IMG NAME=\'seal\' BORDER=\'true\' SRC=\''+seal_gif_url+'\' oncontextmenu=\'return false; \'></A>');
```

You need to escape all the slashes because this Javascript is inside a quoted string in the original script.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, where does the second right parenthesis go?

Comment: Thanks again for responding, unfortunately this did not work and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: You don't have unescaped newlines in `//Some code`, do you?

Comment: Hi Barmar, I deleted all new lines manually. Here is a js fiddle of what I am trying now, http://jsfiddle.net/benPearce/vaxo00eb/. You can see the string is a only one line.

Comment: It looks like the error is happening when jQuery calls `eval("//Some code")`, so I think there's a syntax error somewhere in the code.

Comment: Hi Barmar, I just Implemented the javaScript in a more conventional manner and there were no syntax errors.

Comment: The syntax errors were mostly due to the way you had strings nested within the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping your slashes.

```
<\/script>
```

Also...You planning on declaring these vars anywhere? :P

```
seal_gif_url="images/nortonseal.gif";
dn="www.mysite.com";
sap="getnortonsealimage.js";
splash_url="https://trustsealinfo.verisign.com";
tpt="transparent";
language="en";
u1=splash_url+"/splash?form_file=fdf/splash.fdf&dn="+dn+"&lang="+language;
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the error he's getting?